# Convert set of integers to string in java

Tags: java, string, set

I am trying to convert a set of integers to a single string in Java. How can I do that?

```
 Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(1);
        s.add(3);

        int n = s.size();
        String arr[] = new String[n];

        arr = s.toArray(arr);

        for (String x : arr )
            System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `joining`:

```
String result = s.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(joining());
```

Without `Stream`:

```
List<String> intString = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer i : s) {
   intString.add(String.valueOf(i));
} 

String result = String.join("", intString);
```

But be careful, if you want to print those numbers in input order (which is added first will be printed first), then you'll want a `LinkedHashSet` to remember that order:

```
Set<Integer s = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: Without using streams can I do it?

Comment: I am iterating through an array of numbers and adding them to a LinkedHashSet. Once i have all the required elements in the hash set I would like to convert into a string and then do the work I would like to do..

Comment: If you don't already have imports setup try `collect(Collectors.joining())`

Answer (score 2):

With old-fashioned Java you can do it by using a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (Integer i : s) {
    builder.append(i);
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Integer.toString()` to convert each integer to string and then append it to a `StringBuilder` (also append a space in between to separate integers). Then you can convert `StringBuilder` to `String` and trim it (to remove trailing spaces).

```
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet();
s.add(1);
s.add(3);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int x : s) {
    sb.append(Integer.toString(x));
    sb.append(" ");
}
String st = sb.toString();
st = st.trim();
System.out.print(st);
```